# A suitable data structure to hold the restaurant menu

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures

I have to implement a class (in C#, but I don't think that matters a lot) to hold the list of menu items of the restaurant menu. There are two requirements:

Each item might have a category, which will be then used to output this item. E.g. all the items with category "Drinks" should be output under the label 'Drinks'.

Item might be top-level, i.e. not have a category. These items should be output without any label above them or with some specific label.

The user of this class should be able to easily add items, specifying their category if the item has one.

My current solution is very dirty and it requires that the user of class provides a category no matter if the item has it or not. That is, the user has to create some kind of default category when the items don't have any.

```
public class Menu
{
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

What data structure/class design would be better to solve this issue?

Edit:

It's supposed to print them in some kind of way. To be more accurate, this is the model of menu in the ordering system which might also be present as the text. This model is got from parser and then represented to the user so that they may edit it manually.
 E.g. a user might write something like this in the menu field

> item1 {22}
>
> Item2 {33}
>
> --Category1--
>
> Item3 {44}

and this will be then converted back to the Menu, and then, when the menu is submitted, output in a fancy looking way to the end user.

Updated structure:

After some consideration I've come up with this design:

```
public abstract class MenuItem 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract bool IsCategory();
    public abstract decimal Price();
    public abstract ICollection<MenuItem> Items();
}

public class Dish : MenuItem
{
    private readonly decimal price;

    public Dish(decimal price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public override bool IsCategory()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override decimal Price()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public override ICollection<MenuItem> Items()
    {
        return new List<MenuItem>(); //or null
    }
}

public class Category : MenuItem
{
    public ICollection<MenuItem> Items { get; private set; }

    public Category() : this(new List<MenuItem>()) {    }

    public Category(ICollection<MenuItem> items)
    {
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public override bool IsCategory()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override decimal Price()
    {
        return 0; //or make price nullable and return null
    }

    public override ICollection<MenuItem> Items()
    {
        return Items;
    }
}
```

Where Menu has a list of MenuItem.

Comment: This question is perhaps a bit too broad because there pops up a few questions in my head. For instance, can sideorders be listed several places? Are they distinct menu items or do you want to refer to the menu item several places so that if you change the price for extra hashbrown potatoes for one main course, do all those extras change or only the one you changed? Do you need descriptions? What about localized descriptions (ie. if you're an Italian restaurant you might want to publish italian named dishes, but with english descriptions or names as well).

Comment: In other words, this question might end up more of a discussion about the requirements than the actual implementation of them. I'd say for a basic menu your existing code, minus the collection property setters, seems fine to me at first glance.

Comment: I'd urge you to pick up an actual physical copy of the menu you're supposed to represent, or one very similar at least, and then figuring out how to represent everything. Is this for instance something that is supposed to be used to *print* the menus? Or just to handle them in the ordering system?

Comment: I suggest either to implement two classes implementing a common interface `IMenu`, where the first is ment to be the "top-level"-item and the second class defines a sub-level-item. Other possibility that comes to my mind is to set the `Categories` to NULL which indicates that an item IS a top-level one.

Comment: Added an answer to op post.

Comment: @HimBromBeere 
Yeah, I've considered this and came up with some kind of solution. Gonna add it to the op post.

Comment: Well, if this answered your question you may add it as such and accept it as answer.

Comment: Well, I can say that's definitely better that it was before but I am still not sure if it's solid solution. I have to implement ToString in order to allow a user to convert my model to text representation and with this solution, ToString is the same for Menu and for Category. Btw, what exactly do you mean by 'add it as such and accept it as answer'? Should I answer my own question and mark my answer?